# 10.3 SDE/Enterprise Geodatabase MS SQL missing expiry code in AUTH_key trying to Upgrade to 10.8

Tags: arcgis-10.3, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase

I am trying to upgrade a 10.3.1 Enterprise Geodatabase to 10.8. I come across a potential problem.

I checked the SDE_server_config table to view AUTH_KEY and it says:

```
arcsdeserver,101,ecp#,none,...
```

What happened to the expiry date?
I am sure this will cause an issue during upgrade.
How do I fix it, or do I just continue and try to upgrade to 10.8?

Comment: It's not the lack of expiration date, but the lack of a 10.8 keycode which will slow you down.

Comment: Wouldn't the arcgis server authorization file have the 10.8 keycode required?